# Unpredictable behaviour of scala triple quoted string

Tags: string, scala, junit

I'm using junit in scala to compare string output from my scala code. Something like :

```
val expected = """<Destination id="0" type="EMAIL">
<Address>
    me@test.com
</Address>
<TimeZone>
    US/Eastern
</TimeZone>    
<Message>      
</Message>
</Destination>
"""
 val actual = getTextToLog()
 info(" actual = " + actual)
 assert(expected == actual)
```

The issue is that for some strings, assertions like :

```
assert(expected == actual)
```

work and for some they strings they dont. Even when I copy actual (logged to Eclipse console) from Eclipse console and paste it into expected just to be sure , the assertion still fails.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `expected diff actual` tell you, in these cases?

Comment: Could be something to do with line return encoding. i.e. `\n` (Linux) vs `\r\n` (Windows) vs `\r` (Mac)... or whatever you set up Eclipse to use

Comment: Did you take into account line breaks at the beginning and end of the string?

Comment: There's no problem with Scala's triple quoted strings. The problem lies elsewhere in your code, but, since you don't show anything else, we can't help you.

Comment: Added the method getting the actual text. getTextToLog()  uses a velocity template to return the text and that's all there is really to it.

Comment: Again, go diff the results.  If it's a whitespace issue (which would include the line breaks issue), it'll show up because you'll get a result other than `""`.

Comment: Debug(expected diff actual) prints a bunch of newlines.Thanks for the tip bruce. 
 Any way I can fix the disparity between Eclipse and Scala code. I have do this a lot in Scala Junit tests.

Comment: Use `assertEquals(expected, actual)` instead of `assert(expected == actual)`, so junit will tell you what's the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since this turns out to be a whitespace issues, you should sanitise the two strings before comparing them.  Look at the RichString methods like `.lines`, for example, which might let you create a line-ending or whitespace-agnostic comparison method.

Here is one naive way of doing this with implicit conversions:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
object WhiteSpace {
  implicit def strToWhiteSpace(s: String) = new WhiteSpace(s)
}

class WhiteSpace(val s: String) {
  def `~==` (other: String) = s.lines.toList == other.lines.toList
}
```

which allows

```
import WhiteSpace._
assert(expected ~== actual)
```

Or you could extend the appropriate jutils class to add an agnostic version of `assertEquals`.

Note that this comparison deconstructs both strings in the same way.  This is much safer than sending one of them on a round-trip conversion.

Whitespace/crlf issues are so common that there's no point fighting it by trying to stop the mismatches; just do agnostic comparisons.

Comment: This seems to do the job : 
`def assertEasy(s : String) = {
    val sb = new StringBuffer
    for (str <-  (new StringOps(s)).lines) yield sb.append(str + Properties.lineSeparator)
    sb.toString
  }`

Comment: @Vaibhav You are putting one string through a round-trip conversion away from a multi-line string and then back again.   This is dangerous for several reasons: 1. You might apply it to the wrong string 2. What if neither string matches the lineSeparator property?  Better to apply the same deconstruction to both and compare.  I will update my answer.